# How to prove the following Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let the function $f:\left[  0,T\right]  \times\mathbb{R}
\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function of time $t\in\left[  0,T\right]  $ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, such that the partial derivatives $\partial
f\left(  t,x\right)  /\partial t$ , $\partial f\left(  t,x\right)  /\partial x$ and $\partial^{2}f\left(  t,x\right)  /\partial x^{2}$ exist and are
continuous for all $(t,x)\in\left[  0,T\right]  \times\mathbb{R}$. Then for
any $t,t+\Delta t\in\left[  0,T\right]  $ and $x,x+\Delta x\in\mathbb{R}$,
there exist constants $a,b\in\left[  0,1\right]  $ such that
$$
f\left(  t+\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  -f\left(  t,x\right)  =\frac{\partial
f\left(  t+a\Delta t,x\right)  }{\partial t}\Delta t+\frac{\partial f\left(
t,x\right)  }{\partial x}\Delta x+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}f\left(
t,x+b\Delta x\right)  }{\partial x^{2}}\left(  \Delta x\right)  ^{2}%
$$

Remark, my method
\begin{align*}
&  f\left(  t+\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  -f\left(  t,x\right)  \\
&  =f\left(  t+\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  -f\left(  t,x+\Delta x\right)
+f\left(  t,x+\Delta x\right)  -f\left(  t,x\right)  \\
&  =\frac{\partial f\left(  t+a\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  }{\partial t}\Delta
t+\frac{\partial f\left(  t,x\right)  }{\partial x}\Delta x+\frac{1}{2}%
\frac{\partial^{2}f\left(  t,x+b\Delta x\right)  }{\partial x^{2}}\left(
\Delta x\right)  ^{2}%
\end{align*}
However, the first term is $\frac{\partial f\left(  t+a\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  }{\partial t}\Delta t$ not $\frac{\partial f\left(  t+a\Delta t,x\right)  }{\partial t}\Delta t$, say, the second variable in $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ is not $x$, but $x+\Delta x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is from [A Benchmark Approach to Quantitative Finance](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-47856-0), P230, Lemma 6.6.2.

The first term should be $\frac{\partial f\left(  t+a\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  }{\partial t}\Delta t$. For example, let
 $$f(t,x)=tx^{2} $$ 
we have
 $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=x^{2}\qquad\frac{\partial f}{\partial
x}=2tx\qquad\frac{\partial^{2}f}{\partial x^{2}}=2t $$
We see that if $t=3$, $x=4$, and $\Delta t=\Delta x=1/100$
\begin{align*}
& f\left(  t+\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  -f\left(  t,x+\Delta x\right)  \\
& =\left(  3+\frac{1}{100}\right)  \left(  4+\frac{1}{100}\right)  ^{2}%
-3\cdot\left(  4+\frac{1}{100}\right)  ^{2}\\
& =\left(  4+\frac{1}{100}\right)  ^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{100}
\end{align*}
and
$$
\frac{\partial f\left(  t+a\Delta t,x+\Delta x\right)  }{\partial t}\Delta
t=\left(  4+\frac{1}{100}\right)  ^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{100}
$$
however
 $$\frac{\partial f\left(  t+a\Delta t,x\right)  }{\partial t}\Delta
t=4^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{100}$$